# Set selected option for select not working via $get jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having this problem regarding setting the selected value of a select option using AJAX or more specifically, the $get function of jQuery. I can't seem to make it work. Setting the textbox works fine, but I don't understand why setting the select option won't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $youth_id = $('#youth_id').attr('id');
   $.get("./php-scripts/json-get-youth-details.php", { youth_id: $youth_id },
      function(data) {
         $('input[name="lastname"]').val(data.lastname);
         $('select[name="cellgroup_id"]').val(data.cellgroup_id);
      }, "json");
});
```

I think the problem lies with the order of loading. I think the jQuery loads even before the PHP script in the body section loads. I don't get it because the jQuery script is below the body tag so the body must be loaded even before the script is loaded.

I tried removing the additional scripts to be loaded after the $(document).ready script (see code below) and surprise, surprise, it works. However, I can't remove those scripts since I need them, and I can't put them in front because the UI tags will be changed (because of bootstrap). Oh, I can't find the solution elsewhere!

```
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Insert $(document).ready script here
</script>
<script src="./js/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
<script src="./js/application.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

This is the code that loads the select option:

```
    <select class="span3" tabindex="0" name="cellgroup_id">
        <option value="NULL">N/A</option>
        <?php
            $cellgroupOptions = "";
            include_once("./classes/cellgroup.php");
            $cellgroup = new CellGroup();
            $cellgroupList = $cellgroup->getCellGroupList();
            foreach( $cellgroupList as $cellgroupDetail )
            {
                $cellgroup_id = $cellgroupDetail['cellgroup_id'];
                $cellgroup_name = $cellgroupDetail['cellgroup_name'];
                $cellgroupOptions .=<<<EOT
                        <option value="$cellgroup_id">$cellgroup_name</option>
EOT;
            }
            echo $cellgroupOptions;
            ?>
    </select>
```

As requested, below is the output of the select in HTML after the scripts are loaded (both PHP and Bootstrap). The Bootstrap script changed a lot in the HTML.

```
<div class="dk_container span3 dk_shown dk_theme_default" id="dk_container_cellgroup_id" tabindex="0">
   <a class="dk_toggle">
      <span class="dk_label">N/A</span>
      <span class="select-icon"></span>
   </a>
   <div class="dk_options">
      <ul class="dk_options_inner">
         <li class="dk_option_current"><a data-dk-dropdown-value="NULL">N/A</a></li>
         <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="1">Arrows of God</a></li>
         <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="2">Fishmen</a></li></ul></div></div>
      </ul></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can guarantee you that the jQuery does not load before the PHP.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks! So, what could be the problem? Apparently, setting the textbox works fine, but I don't understand why setting the select option won't work. (edited the 1st paragraph and the 1st code block)

Comment: Are you sure that value exists in your select options list?

Comment: @tymeJV EDITED. Yup! I tried to hard code it outside the $.get function and it works:
`$('select[name="cellgroup_id"]').val("1");` I also tried this code inside the $.get function, and it works. So, I made sure that the value '1' is being returned by data.cellgroup_id by using alert. It does, but I don't know why it is not changing the selected value.

Comment: Inside your `$.get`, hard code the value again. Does it set it or ignore it?

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the generated select?

Comment: Now that is interesting...and your absolutely positive that `data.cellgroup_id` is returning the EXACT value that you just hard coded?

Comment: @tymeJV Sorry! My mistake! Even the hard coded value inside the `$.get` doesn't work. I apparently left the hard coded value outside the `$.get` that's why I thought it does work.

Yes, I'm very sure the exact value is being hard coded. I checked it many times now.

Comment: Is the `$.get` callback being ran? Throw a log statement or an alert inside that `$.get` function after the statement that sets the value, is it being triggered?

Comment: @tymeJV I tried putting `alert(data.cellgroup_id)` after the line where the select value is set. The alert box shows up showing the number 1. Does that mean the callback is triggered? I appreciate much your help tymeJV!

Comment: I'm really going to hate if it's this, try setting the value like this: `$('select[name="cellgroup_id"]').val("'" + data.cellgroup_id + "'");`

Comment: @tymeJV Haha. I tried it, but it doesn't work. I think the problem really is in the split second order of loading.

Comment: I'm at a loss...I don't see why those other scripts are interfering.. +1 to the question tho, hopefully someone else comes along to figure this out. I'll stick around, see if anything pops into my head.

Comment: I believe posting the output HTML of your select will help resolve the issue

Comment: @koala_dev Sorry bout that. I've edited my post to show the HTML output of the select (lower part of the post).

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to remove the `$.get` script out of the `$(document).ready` event. As I refresh it numerous times, sometimes it's working, sometimes it's not. Weeirrd! @tymeJV You think this is an important discovery?

Comment: There's the thing, you're not using a standard select input so your jQuery code won't work...

Comment: @koala_dev Nope, that's not a problem. That's a boostrap thing. It's fine as long as I run the setting script before the bootstrap is loaded. That's why if I hard code the `$('select[name="cellgroup_id"]').val("1");` outside the `$.get`, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution!

So, the `$.get` function really has some issues with how it loads. This is how I fixed it:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $youth_id = $('input[name="youth_id"]').val();
    $.get("./php-scripts/json-get-youth-details.php", { youth_id: $youth_id },
    function(data) {
        $('select[name="cellgroup_id"]').val(data.cellgroup_id);

        $.getScript("./js/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js");
        $.getScript("./js/jquery.tagsinput.js");
        $.getScript("./js/bootstrap-tooltip.js");
        $.getScript("./js/jquery.placeholder.js");
        $.getScript("http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js");
        $.getScript("./js/application.js");
    }, "json");
});
```

I had to put the loading of the other scripts only inside the `$.get` code also. It ensures that the values has been set and done before even loading the other scripts.

Phew! Thanks for the help guys!